Series representation of $\cos(x)$ and $e^{-x^2}$ and cancellations.
I realized that:
$$\cos(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
is above 1/2 for abitrary large value of $x$ whereas
$$e^{-x^2} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{k!}$$
has a really strong decay at infinity.
What surprised me is the fact that when looking only
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!} \qquad \text{ and } \qquad \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{k!},$$
one can naively think that the series on the left is "smaller" than the serie on the right ($(2k)!$ is way larger than $k!$). But, the sign $(-1)^k$ has to be taken into account.
My question is the following: without computing the sums of the two previous series, is it possible to prove that the one corresponding to $e^{-x^2}$ is negligeable regarding the one corresponding to $\cos(x)$, when considering good values of $x$.
Moreover, is there a natural explanation of such phenomena of "cancelation between terms" ?

These are alternating series. If you group the terms by {2n,2n+1} you will se that a faster decay in absolute value means  bigger value

Ok, that's great. But, $\sum_{k \geq 0} (-1)^k x^{2k}/{(k!)^{0.01}}$ may be really large no ?

Yeah, but it fulfils the criteria of alternating series up to a certain rank
